# Why aren't there `!`s before errors anymore in LaTeX compilation results?

Tags: errors, output

I've just installed the latest version of MikTeX (2016), upgrading from 2015.  I write in Emacs, using AUCTeX (though I'm pretty sure that Emacs and AUCTeX aren't relevant to my question.)

Before updating, whenever I got an error message, the errors were marked with a `!` (as well as the line number) in the LaTeX compilation results.  This meant that I could find the errors quickly, just using Emacs's search command to find the exclamation points.

But now, the errors are no longer marked with any particular string that I can search for, and it's much more time-consuming to find my errors.

Is there something I'm not seeing?  And if not, what can I do?

Comment: web2ctex (including texlive and miktex) will use the standard TeX `!` unless the `--file-line-error` flag is given in which case the `!` is replaced by the filename and line number.

Comment: I think auctex uses filelineerror to make it easier for it to parse the log to find errors  (C-c n scrolls through the errors, you shouldn't have to find them "by hand"(

Comment: @David Carlisle From which buffer is `C-c n` supposed to work?  For me, it's undefined in both the `.tex` buffer which is in `(LaTeX/P Fill)` mode and the compilation results buffer

Comment: sorry `C-c \`` (see C-h w next-error  )